# The Itō isometry for Riemannian manifolds

Tags: pr.probability, riemannian-geometry, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

If $\alpha$ is a real smooth $1$-form, and if $\mathcal C$ is the space of continuous functions $c : [0,1] \to \mathbb R^n$, endowed with the Wiener measure $w$, and if $I_\alpha : \mathcal C \to \mathbb R$ is the Itō stochastic integral, then the *Itō isometry* is the name given to the equality

$$ \| I_\alpha \| _{L^2 (\mathcal C, w)} ^2 = \int _{\mathcal C} \int _0 ^1 \| \alpha _{c(t)} \| ^2 \ \mathrm d t \ \mathrm d w (c) \ .$$

> Does a similar relation exist if $\mathbb R^n$ is replaced by an arbitrary connected Riemannian manifold $M$? (Or, if not arbitrary, then at least subjected to some conditions?)

I am looking for something like

$$ \| I_\alpha \| _{L^2 (\mathcal C, w)} ^2 \le C \int _{\mathcal C} \int _0 ^1 \| \alpha _{c(t)} \| ^2 \ \mathrm d t \ \mathrm d w (c) \ ,$$

with $C>0$ depending on the manifold (notice that the equality has become an inequality).